# MFMailComposeViewController UIActionSheet position in iPhone 5 long screen

Tags: ios, ios6, uiactionsheet, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am in the middle of porting an old app to fit the longer screen of iPhone 5. I am wondering why the built-in `UIActionSheet (Cancel)` of `MFMailComposeViewController` is not aligned to bottom, as shown:

[image]

Is this controlled by the parent view? Where should I take a look into?

Comment: Can you post the code how you present the MFMailComposeViewController?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this piece of code in app delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method

```
[window setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open iPhone Email application, then use below code.So, you have not any need to  add `MFMailComposeViewController`.

```
NSString *subject = @"";

 NSString *body = @"";

 NSString *address = @"test@gmail.com";

 NSString *cc = @"";

 NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@?cc=%@&subject=%@&body=%@", address, cc,
   subject, body];

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```